# git - couldn't resolve proxy '0' error

Tags: git, proxy

I receive this error when I try to push my code changes to git -

```
error: Couldn't resolve proxy '0' while accessing https://github.com/pavanred/Radar-chart-utility-.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I was able to push to git a couple of days ago, I am not sure why this stopped working suddenly?

I have searched the internet but I couldn't find any answers. I am working from my home network and I do not have a proxy server, all the help I could get from the internet suggested me to provide my proxy information, but i don't have one. How can i solve this?

Comment: Try setting environment variable `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` to see some further information about what is happening... also, have you checked you don't have any "ghost" proxies in your `git config -l` output? Provide that, too, if there is any mention of proxies.

Comment: I set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE = 1 but didnt get any more information than what I have already posted. And, I tried git config -l and there wasn't any mention of any proxy.

Comment: did the variable work, was there at least change in output? was there mention of any proxy other than this? does this happen on other repositories? do you have some other computer within the same network that you could test the git connection with? or some other os (using a virtual machine, dual boot, live cd configuration or similar)?

Comment: Well, there was absolutely no change in the output other than this. It happens with all repositories. I dont have any other computer on the same network but I have a dual boot. I dont have git in there, I can try that and let you know.

Comment: used dual boot, it works fine on linux. But, the problem still exists on windows 7 ! Not sure what the reason is..

Comment: ok, so it's something specific to there then. do you use cmd prompt, cygwin bash, mingw or which shell? can you try if the situation is the same if you use for example cmd prompt instead of mingw, or other way around?

Comment: also, if you have global .gitconfig, could you try renaming that - just in case if it has some other error that is affecting

Comment: and check if you have http_proxy defined

Comment: I have already tried using http_proxy and https_proxy to "" and "0". But, well didn't solve the problem.

Comment: you should definitely not set the variable if you don't have a proxy. So please confirm it is not set. How about the other things I asked?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure to unset any proxy:

```sh
cd /path/to/repo

git config --unset http.proxy
git config --unset https.proxy

git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

Second, on Windows (7 or 10), for testing in your CMD, type:

```sh
set HTTP_PROXY=
set HTTPS_PROXY=
```

Then try again.